# Can't get jquery script to work in django admin StackedInline model field

Tags: python, jquery, django, django-models, django-admin

(Sorry this is slightly convoluted)

I have 2 django models (`recipe` and `ingredient` -- code below).

```
class Recipe(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    servings = models.IntegerField()
    tags = TaggableManager()


    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

```
class Ingredient(models.Model):
    recipe = models.ForeignKey(Recipe, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=50)
    numerical = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    quantity=models.IntegerField(default=0)
    measurement = models.CharField(max_length=20)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I registered this models so that I can edit ingredients inline from the recipe view within the admin page. (see image) [image]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Recipe, Ingredient
from django_summernote.admin import SummernoteModelAdmin


class IngredientAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Ingredient
    extra = 0
    #exclude = ('urls',)

class RecipeAdmin(SummernoteModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'servings', 'tags')
    list_filter = ("tags",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'tags']
    inlines = [IngredientAdmin]
    summernote_fields = '__all__'
    class Meta:
       model = Recipe


class IngredientAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    pass

admin.site.register(Recipe, RecipeAdmin)
admin.site.register(Ingredient, IngredientAdmin)
```

Now I want to make the ingredient's field `quantity` disappear if the `numerical` checkbox is set to False.

I was able to do this within the Admin-ingredients's view following [this post](https://www.djangoadmintutorials.com/django-admin-how-to-show-or-hide-fields-in-change-form-based-on-another-field-value/) and copying the Admin `change_form.html` into `<appname>/templates/admin/ingredient/change_form.html` and adding the following javascript to the `{% block admin_change_form_document_ready %}` section.
[image]

```
<script>
    django.jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        if (django.jQuery('#id_numerical').is(':checked')) {
             hide_quantity=false;
        } else {
             var elementQuantity = document.getElementsByClassName("form-row field-quantity");
             var i;
             for (i = 0; i < elementQuantity.length; i++) {
                elementQuantity[i].style ="display: none!important";
             }
            hide_quantity=true;
        }
        django.jQuery("#id_numerical").click(function(){
            hide_quantity=!hide_quantity;
            if (hide_quantity) {
                var elementQuantity = document.getElementsByClassName("form-row field-quantity");
                 var i;
                 for (i = 0; i < elementQuantity.length; i++) {
                    elementQuantity[i].style ="display: none!important";
                 }
            } else {
                 var elementQuantity = document.getElementsByClassName("form-row field-quantity");
                 var i;
                 for (i = 0; i < elementQuantity.length; i++) {
                    elementQuantity[i].style ="display: block!important";
                 }
            }
        })
    })
    </script>
```

**HOWEVER**, I can't get this to work within the recipe admin view. I tried copying the `change_form.html` into `<appname>/templates/admin/recipe/change_form.html` but all I get is that the `quantity` field is always hidden.

I believe it has something to do with the fact that the `django.jQuery('#id_numerical').is(':checked'))` part of the script isn't correct anymore because I am editing ingredients as an stackedinline element of the recipe admin view.

Any help?

Comment: Check what the id should be in the browsers developer tools?

Comment: Ok! Using the dev-tool I was able to identify that the id for the first ingredient was `id_ingredient_set-0-numerical`. I hard coded that one in the `change_form.html` and it worked! 

However, now I am facing a different challenge since the next ingredient  has id `id_ingredient_set-1-numerical`. Any idea of how can I account for that incremental value (0,1,2 et cetera?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery's [Attribute starts with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [Attribute ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) selectors by chaining them like so:

```
django.jQuery("[id^='id_ingredient_set-'][id$='-numerical']")
```

But I would suggest setting a custom class attribute on the inputs. To do this you would set a custom form on the admin class:

```
from django import forms

class IngredientForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Ingredient
        widgets = {
            'numerical': forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'class': 'my-numerical-class'}),
        }
        fields = '__all__'
        

class IngredientAdmin(admin.StackedInline):
    model = Ingredient
    extra = 0
    form = IngredientForm
    #exclude = ('urls',)
```

Now you can simply select the correct elements using:

```
django.jQuery(".my-numerical-class")
```